# Is it possible to create a Spring 5 Component Index using ANT?

Tags: spring, indexing, ant

I've seen plenty of examples for how to do this using Maven or Gradle, but I haven't seen anyone show how to do it using ANT.  Is it possible?  And if so, how?

Comment: I'd start [here](https://maven.apache.org/resolver-ant-tasks/). The short answer is "yes" because ultimately you can do pretty much anything in Ant. The other short answer is it might be time to start considering dropping Ant.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately I work at a large company whose entire build infrastructure is based off of Ant, so switching to Maven or Gradle isn't really under my control.